# is there any way i can give multiple lines in gcloud ssh --command argument?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

I'm trying to install an agent from gcloud for multiple instances,

```
gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a --command="sudo su - && mkdir /tmp && cd /tmp && ..."
```

steps to cover :

1. sudo su -
2. mkdir /tmp
3. cd /tmp
4. download an agent
5. install it

how to run multiple lines of script from gcloud compute ssh --command= ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a heredoc but you should not include the `sudo` in the script that you want to run as root:

```sh
# Create SCRIPT 
read -r -d '' SCRIPT <<EOF
mkdir /tmp
cd /tmp
...
EOF

gcloud compute ssh ${NAME} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--command="sudo ${SCRIPT}"
```

It may be better to install the agent using a [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts). Using `--command` requires the script to be passed as a variable and tends to be more ad hoc.

Comment: i have around 50 vms and need to install 3-4 agents , and also startup script requires the vm to be restarted